# Querying with objects.extra in django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

How can i query with to_tsquery for partial words match

For example
 records

```
'hello old world'
'hello world'
'hi welcome'
'hi'
```

Here i wanted to return all records which includes words 'hello' or 'welcome'

```
SELECT * FROM accounts_order
WHERE name_tsvector @@ to_tsquery('english','hello | welcome');
```

This returns properly.
Here i tried to implement using django 'objects.extra' query

```
queryset = Order.objects.extra(where=['name_tsvector @@ to_tsquery(%s|%s)'], params=['hello','welcome'])
```

This query is nor working,got an exception

```
operator is not unique: unknown | unknown
LINE 1: ...nts_order" WHERE name_tsvector @@ to_tsquery(E'olmin'|E'20')
                                                            ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can i pass this params part as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want the `|` within the string, ie a boolean `OR` in the `tsquery`:

```
regress=> select to_tsquery('english', 'olmin|20');
   to_tsquery   
----------------
 'olmin' | '20'
(1 row)
```

Django is expanding `%s` to `E'string'`, so you can't write `%s|%s`; as you've seen that expands to `E'string1'|E'string2'` which is interpreted as a boolean `OR` on the two strings. You must either:

- Concatenate the two strings and `|` in Django with (eg) `params=['hello'+'|'+'welcome']` and a single `(%s)` argument; or
- Get Pg to concatenate the two strings with a literal `|`, eg `(%s||'|'||%s)`

I'd recommend the first option; it requires you to change the parameters you pass from Python but it produces vastly simpler SQL.

The original is invalid, it's trying to perform a boolean `OR` on two string literals:

```
regress=> select to_tsquery('english', 'olmin'|'20');
ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown | unknown
LINE 1: select to_tsquery('english', 'olmin'|'20');
                                            ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: I am expecting query result  same as that of SELECT * FROM accounts_order
WHERE name_tsvector @@ to_tsquery('english','olmin' | '20');

Comment: @Jafarali The `|` operator is bitwise `OR`. You want the `||` operator, string concatenation.

Comment: @Jafarali ... unless you're trying to do an `OR` *within* the `tsquery`, in which case keep the `|` within the tsquery string. See amended answer.

Comment: @Jafarali Can you edit your question to explain what you want to match? Maybe provide some sample inputs and show what queries you want to match.

Comment: @Jafarali OK, makes more sense. Answer updated. Basically, do the string concatenation in Python so you send a single string `olmin|20` to the DB, or create a statement with a correctly formatted SQL string concatenation expression. The former will be much, much simpler.